# Building complex object inside or outside the class in Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to get the best practice in Java to solve the following problem :

I want to setup an complex object in one place, so that other clients can then reuse this construction. Here is an example and how I proceed :

My complex object is of type "Ontology", this object contains many parameters, once it is instantiated and filled, it is used in many objects as a kind of configuration by using its getter.

My Ontology.class

```java
abstract class Ontology {
   List<Something1> param1;
   List<Something2> param2;
   ...

   protected void addParam1(){
      ...
   }

   ....

   abstract protected void setup();
}
```

A way to hold the complex construction :

```java
public class SpecificOntology extend Ontology{          
   @Override
   protected void setup(){
       addParam1(new Something(...));
       ...
   }
}
```

A client :

```java
 protected void something(){
     SpecificOntology o = new SpecificOntology();
     o.setup();

     install(o.getParam1(());
     ...  
 }
```

Another solution could be to make Ontology not abstract, make its Adder public and build the object outside of the class, but I don't know which pattern could be used for that ? I know the builder pattern and the factory pattern but I am not sure this is the right place for that. Any idea ?

Comment: So for a specific configuration the parameters will always be the same? For example one of the settings won't be a number that changes?

Comment: I ask because depending on what the parameters are... my advice will be different. If the parameters are a set of other objects I think that you are overlooking the abstract factory pattern which does exactly what you are describing by simplifying the creation a concrete object composed of different but related object. If the parameters 1 ...n are all of the same object and are extremely variable then an alteration to the Builder Pattern may be best route.

Comment: Each parameter is different but related, I will take a look at the abstract factory pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build an object with many parameters, the first thing I would think of is the Builder pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure, with the builder pattern clients of the Ontology class are still concerned by the construction process, right ? I would like that clients use this class as  they could use a configuration file edited by a user, in this case the author of the SpecificOntology.

Comment: If all the parameter values will be set by the author of SpecificOntology, we don't even need the abstract setup method - just set all the values in the constructor. Therefore, the client does not need to call setup on the constructed object (if the client forgets to do that the object will be used will not initialized values - nothing good can come out of it). If the client needs to adjust some of the parameters, just expose them by setters.